# Incorrect output from quadratic equation program

Tags: python, python-2.7

The user is supposed to put in a value for A, B, and C and get the roots of the quadratic equation. Mathematically, my code gives the wrong answer:

```
print "Quadratic Formula Calculator!!!"

a = input("Please, enter value for A: ")
b = input("Please, enter value for B: ")
c = input("Please, enter value for C: ")

quad =(b**2 - 4 * a * c)

if quad >= 0:
    quad ** 0.5
    print "quad"

else:
    print "can not compute"

solution1 = (-b + quad) / (2 * a)
solution2 = (b + quad) / (2 * a)

print " Solution 1!!!:", solution1
print " Soultion 2!!!:", solution2
```

Comment: -1. Your quadratic formula is wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to compute? What output do you expect for which input? Please explain your problem properly.

Comment: I think you want to solve `a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0`, but it would have been helpful if you posted the problem you want to solve. Also I guess this is python-2.7 code, not python 3.x, so it would be polite if you edit the question and remove the not-matching tag. (ah, I see martijn peters already fixed that).

Comment: The thing that you are calling "quad" is known as the discriminant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant. "Quad" has other connotations that I would avoid.

Answer (score 4):

You need this:

```
quad = quad ** 0.5
```

Instead of just `quad ** 0.5`.

And solutions are:

```
(-b + quad) / (2 * a)
(-b - quad) / (2 * a)
```

And if you can not compute for negative values of discriminant (you can, the answer would be a complex conjugate values), just move calculating and printing of solution inside the `quad >= 0`.

Comment: I tried that, Python keeps giving me this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\quadratic.py", line 10, in <module>
    quad = quad ** 0.5
ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power" I don't know how to fix this

Comment: How it can be negative if there is a condition just right before it?

Comment: which input values cause that Traceback ?

Comment: You could use the cmath library for that: `from cmath import sqrt`

Comment: @JasonSperske: Are you sure about **cmath**?

Comment: @m0nhawk I'm seldom sure of anything, but in this case, why do you ask?  I updated the gist to show the two distinct roots if they exist

Answer (score 2):

Building on m0nhawk's answer, Hooked's comment (and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation)) here is an approach that uses the [cmath library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) designed for complex numbers.

```
from math import pow
from cmath import sqrt

print "Quadradtic Formula Calculator!!!"
print "Ax²+Bx+C=0"
print "This will attempt to solve for x"

a = input("Please, enter value for A: ")
b = input("Please, enter value for B: ")
c = input("Please, enter value for C: ")

discriminant = sqrt(pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c))

if discriminant.imag != 0:
    print "discriminant is imaginary"
else:
    print " Solution 1!!!:", (-b + discriminant.real) / (2 * a)
    print " Solution 2!!!:", (-b - discriminant.real) / (2 * a)
```

`cmath.sqrt` will return a complex number with `.imag` and `.real` fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
solution1 = (-b + quad) / (2 * a)
solution2 = (b + quad) / (2 * a)
```

This should be

```
solution1 = (-b + quad) / (2 * a)
solution2 = (-b - quad) / (2 * a)
```

The formula is -b plus or minus the root, not plus or minus b plus the root.